# Сортировка змейкой массива Js

Tags: javascript

Нужно отсортировать массив змейкой по такому принципу:

```
 =>max  
<=  
=>  
<=min
```

Есть код, в нем завел 2 функции, на мин и  макс. Объясните, пожалуйста, как и где в этом коде реализовать подобную сортировку. Заранее спасибо!

```
var n = prompt('Введите размерность таблицы: ');    

function getRandomInt(min, max){//Функция для генерации случайного числа
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function Increase(a, b) {//Функция для сортировки массива по возрастанию
    return a - b;
}

function Decrease(a, b) {//Функция для сортировки массива по убыванию
    return b - a;
}

function CreateAnArray(rows,columns){ //Функция, которая создаёт двумерный массив
    var arr = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<rows; i++){
        arr[i] = new Array();

        for(var j=0; j<columns; j++){
            arr[i][j] = getRandomInt(0, 100);
        }
    }

    return arr;
}


var myMatrix = CreateAnArray(n,n); //Вызов функции для создания массива


var elem = document.querySelector('#elemTwo');//Присваем переменной селектор
createTable(elem, n, n);//Вызываем функцию и передаем ей параметр n

function createTable(parent, rows, cols){ //Функция для вывода массива на странницу
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for(var j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerHTML=myMatrix[i][j]; // используем уже отсортированный массив
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
    parent.appendChild(table);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была создана новая функция `SortAnArray`, которая перебирает уже созданный массив любой размерности и создает на его базе новый. В зависимости от индекса переданного подмассива, а точнее от его остатка после деления на 2 мы выбираем: по убыванию или по возрастанию будем сортировать подмассив. Затем `myMatrix` перезаписываем на отсортированный массив, а дальше сам знаешь.

```js
var n = prompt('Введите размерность таблицы: ');

function getRandomInt(min, max) { //Функция для генерации случайного числа
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function Increase(a, b) { //Функция для сортировки массива по возрастанию
  return a - b;
}

function Decrease(a, b) { //Функция для сортировки массива по убыванию
  return b - a;
}

function SortAnArray(arr) {
  var newArr = [];
  arr.forEach((item, index) => {
    newArr.push(item.sort(index % 2 ? Decrease : Increase));
  });
  return newArr;
}

function CreateAnArray(rows, columns) { //Функция, которая создаёт двумерный массив
  var arr = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    arr[i] = new Array();

    for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = getRandomInt(0, 100);
    }
  }

  return arr;
}


var myMatrix = CreateAnArray(n, n); //Вызов функции для создания массива
myMatrix = SortAnArray(myMatrix);


var elem = document.querySelector('body'); //Присваем переменной селектор
createTable(elem, n, n); //Вызываем функцию и передаем ей параметр n

function createTable(parent, rows, cols) { //Функция для вывода массива на странницу
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerHTML = myMatrix[i][j]; // используем уже отсортированный массив
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
  parent.appendChild(table);
}
```